# Joining multiple tables gives me too many sums

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have two tables: 1. EMP (holds employees info) and 2. activities (contains empid, status: working, leave).
The status might duplicate, so I can have the same status repeated for the same date.

I want my output to be in these columns:

```
 emp absence working
---- ------- --------
```

My query looks like:

```
select id ,employee, count(tr)as [working] , count(om) as [Absence]
from(
    ( select emp_id as id,  rep as employee from emp) as [pc101]
    left outer join
    (
    select distinct emp_id, mydate as [tr]
    from activities
    where status = "Working"
    ) as [pc1]

on pc1.emp_id = pc101.id
)
left outer join
    (
    select distinct emp_id, mydate as [om]
    from activities
    where status = "absent"
    ) as pc2
on pc101.id = pc2.emp_id
group by employee, id
```

I used the left outer join to make sure even the Employees who do not match the criteria will appear.
The problem is that when employees have both statuses the value is summed for both working & absence.

Comment: Please share sample data & desired output.

Comment: add the status column to the criteria for the *left outer join* clause.

Comment: Thank you Peiter! Worked like a charm!